# Why do square integrable functions have to be isolated at infinity?

Tags: measure-theory, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Why the functions of square integrable vanish at infinity?
I have read about quantum mechanics, is a condition for statistical interpretation and these functions live in Hilbert space, but I have been searching because the integrable square functions vanish at infinity and I have not found anything, is there a demonstration or where it gives me a reason for this?
Has it to do with measurement theory?

Comment: There actually are functions which do not have $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ but are square-integrable. But they would be rather unusual for a physics context.

Comment: So, what is the physical meaning of the wave function vanishing at infinity?

Comment: It means for example that an electron near a nucleus is extremely unlikely to be measured a kilometer away or with momentum 1 kg*m/s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't; if $f$ is supported on $[0,1]$ and has squared integral $1$ then $g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k^2(x-k))$ is square integrable and doesn't vanish at infinity. (The summands here are the same shape as $f$ but shifted $k$ steps to the right and then squished horizontally by a factor of $k^2$ without being squished vertically.)

These don't come up in physics but it is for physical reasons, not on the grounds of square integrability per se.

Comment: So, what is the physical meaning of the wave function vanishing at infinity?

Comment: If the wave function represents a probability of the location of the particle, what's the physical interpretation of having a non-zero probability of existing at infinity?

Comment: @ConMan That unfortunately doesn't actually answer the question, because "vanish at infinity" is really an asymptotic statement, not a literal statement (there is no "point at infinity" to find the particle at all). And indeed, the probability to find a particle with wavefunction given by $\frac{\sqrt{6}}{\pi} g$ outside some $[0,M]$ goes to zero as $M \to \infty$. The issue actually has more to do with how you would ever prepare a potential that would get a wavefunction into that state in the first place.

Comment: True, I guess my QM is a little rusty.